# Exporting image to new format within directory

Tags: windows-11, shortcuts

I am very new to Windows: Have been using MacOS this whole time and still am for my laptop. I am having difficulty getting used to the structure of this system because of the great difference with MacOS. I would like to know if there is any shortcut to exporting images to another format without having to open an application, such as Paint or even Adobe Photoshop? Below is an example of what it looks like for the MacOS:

[image: MacOS with shortcuts]

This is not my image so I must say it is from [here](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2019/07/22/create-quick-actions-mac-finder/), but it displays a similar function of what I'm trying to explain, which is how MacOS does have the option for letting us customize the buttons in Finder (directory source). On my MacOS I enabled it to recognize photos that are not PNG, and if not then it includes a button that converts it to a PNG. I'm wondering if there is an easy way to set up a shortcut similar to that on Windows? From what I have searched, I only got results of still having to use Microsoft applications or others.

Comment: There is nothing similar that is built in into Win11. But you could probably achieve something similar by using an external program